# Systemd: pipe input to daemonized server?

Tags: systemd, pipe

So I have a server that I can run from a bash terminal using e.g.

```
java -jar spigot.jar
```

which will send output to stdout (I believe), and thus be printed to the terminal screen. To stop the server from the terminal, one simply sends the "stop" command to the server, at which point the server initiates shutdown (saves current data, etc.).

However, I don't want to have to start the server every time I reboot, or have an extra bash terminal hanging around with the open process, so I've been trying to set up a systemd service to run the server automatically, and take standard input from (anywhere, really), using a .service file like the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Spigot Minecraft server daemon

[Service]
Restart=always
WorkingDirectory=*location where spigot.jar is*

StandardInput=tty
TTYPath=/dev/tty2

ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar spigot.jar
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c 'echo stop >/dev/tty2'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But I can't figure out why this won't work. What I thought it should do is pipe /dev/tty2 to the server, and when I use the command

```
systemctl stop *service*
```

it should send "stop" (indirectly through /dev/tty2) to the server. What am I missing?

But the service doesn't seem to run? If I comment out the StandardInput & TTYPath lines, the server starts, but when issuing

```
systemctl stop *service*
```

and then reviewing server logs through

```
journalctl -u *service*
```

the proper shutdown sequence never initiated -- the process was just killed (instead of gracefully stopping itself).

So what I want to know is: how do I run this server as a service, with some FIFO/file/tty/something piped into it (so I can still issue server commands)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you are trying too hard. The standard way to shutdown a service is send it a SIGTERM signal (polite) or a SIGKILL signal (forceful). I believe that's the default `systemd` behavior. So try removing all these lines from your `systemd` unit file:

```
StandardInput=tty
TTYPath=/dev/tty2
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c 'echo stop >/dev/tty2'
```

[There are plenty or references on the Spogit site to using SIGTERM and SIGKILL](https://www.spigotmc.org/search/16385956/?q=sigterm&o=relevance)

Comment: That might be true for the particular case of `spigot`, but the OP question about how to pipe to a daemon remains unanswered.

Comment: You don't. You communicate with a daemon via signals, sockets, ports, IPC or some other mechanism.

Comment: Too bad the official Minecraft server (not spigot) does not handle signals in a standard way :-(. There's no signal to gracefully stop it and make it save all world data before exiting. SIGTERM (and all the others I tried) simply shut it down.